# Windows 10 April 2018 update cause Apache24 to shut down

Tags: apache, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro which runs WAMP.  A Windows 10 April 2018 update was done last night and now my Apache24 server stopped working.

I did some checking by trying to start Apache httpd.exe from the command line and it returns this message:
"AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down"

In the Apache httpd.conf file I changed the Listen from Listen 80 to Listen 127.0.0.1:80 to match what's in the hosts file.  After saving the files; did a restart and ran httpd.exe again, I still got this message:

"AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80 AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down".

My Apache24 server works perfect before this windows 10 update. 
Does anyone know what could have caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue by doing the following:
I took another Windows 10 pro workstation which also has the WAMP installation on it. This box did not get the April 2018 update.  I then compared the Services running on both boxes and found that the box with the windows update had “World Wide Web Publishing Service” running while the other box did not have such a service.  This tells me that the windows update turns on the service and set it to autostart.
I turned off the service by stopping the “World Wide Web Publishing Service” from running, and then start Apache from the Apache HTTP server monitor which was successful.  I then went back and set the “World Wide Web Publishing Service” to manual start before restarting it.

Comment: I had the same problem with the November 2018 Windows 10 update, this was the cause and resolution.